# Colors changed when uploaded as png

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

When I export the image from Photoshop as a JPG and upload it, everything looks how it should:

[image]
https://s15.postimg.org/xfh3fc08r/image.jpg

But the same image, exported and uploaded as a PNG, and I get this monstrosity:

[image]
https://s4.postimg.org/xyxw8w02l/trc.png

Side-by-side comparison:

[image]
https://s2.postimg.org/6dsv7vw1l/seo1.jpg

When I view the PNG image on my computer, the color is intact. It's only when I upload the thing it starts looking like crap.

Any idea what's causing this and how I can fix it?

---

Some updates:

I just figured out a part of the problem: The png only become darker when upload when I export the png using the "Quick Export as PNG" option in CC2015. If I use "Save as" and choose PNG, it can be upload without issues.

I mess around with the color profile, and found the upload color when I export is exactly like adobe RGB. I went into assign color profile and pick sRGB, but whenever I export and upload, it still look like it's adobe RGB. Save as remain unaffected.

Any idea?

Comment: The color looks exactly the same in both to me

Comment: That's weird. This is a side by side comparison, you can see the png is much darker: https://s2.postimg.org/6dsv7vw1l/seo1.jpg

Comment: Yeh pretty much still look the same, and I've checked on a bunch of screens/devices

Comment: Upload where??? There are a billion places to upload an image. Many will processes jpgs differently than png files.  And some will even treat png as if ti IS jpg.

Comment: The colours are precisely the same in all four versions, as far as I can tell. Perhaps it’s the uploading that does it, but overlaying the different versions on top of each other in Photoshop reveals no difference in colour whatsoever.

Comment: The obvious question: Are you just annoyed about the transparency?

Answer (score 0):

I see the color difference in the side by side. Are you viewing in photoshop locally and in a browser after uploading? Or viewing the saved file locally in a browser?

Also: are you saving as a 24 bit PNG using export or save for web, or are you just doing a save as and picking PNG from the file type drop down?

If you haven't yet: try doing a Save For Web, choose PNG 24, leave transparency turned off. Upload and check. If that doesn't match, try doing the same thing but unchecking the transparency box.

Answer (score 0):

When a PNG with transparency is shown, at some point - in the website or at least in the browser- some background must be inserted. In some cases the chosen background is black. I have seen this many times when I copy an image from the screen and try to paste it to Photoshop. It has got a full black background. If I download the PNG properly, it's ok and the background is transparent. GIMP does not add black background to the same clipboard content.

I cannot see any difference between your JPG and the monstrosity. Both seem to have same colours and the same white background onscreen.

If I desaturate the side by side comparison image and take an averages of the non-background areas separately, both are the same 60% grey:

[image]

Actually the left version has average RGB values =153 and the right version =152 but that can be caused by the different selections.

Try to remove the color info from the transparent pixels or set is white, but still fully transparent. At least that can be done in GIMP easily. That does not quarantee anything except nobody suggests to generate a black background. To keep all in control, have background of the wanted color.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop shows very little difference between the two...

Here is the result of applying the 'Difference' blending mode to the image on top:

[image: Difference visualized]

In this image any pixels which are black are unchanged... and this image appears largely black.